# trying to write a basic echo function that also checks a mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I don't understand where the error is coming from but know I am not good at writing MySQL queries, but am not sure if that would throw off the entire function.

php:

```
    function createTable($name, $query)
    {
        if (tableExists($name))
        {
            echo "Table '$name' already exists.<br />";
        }
    }
     function createplayer ($name, $allegiance, $element, $age)
 {
    if (tableExists($name)) {
        //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\phpscripts\functions.php on line 39

        echo "Player $name already exists.<br />";
        //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\phpscripts\functions.php on line 57
    }
        else {queryMysql("INSERT INTO players   
        VALUES'$name', '$age', '$birthdate', '$element', '$allegiance'")
        }
}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\robotcity\phpscripts\rcfunctions.php on line 61

Comment: `echo "Player "$name" already exists.<br />";` change that to `echo "Player $name already exists.<br />";` that's where your parse error is coming from.

Comment: Or `"Player \"$name\" already exists.<br />"` if you want the name to be quoted in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement is out of context without the relavant curly braces:

```
function createTable($name, $query)
{
    if (tableExists($name))
    {
        echo "Table '$name' already exists.<br />";
    }
}
function createplayer ($name, $allegiance, $element, $age)
{
    if (tableExists($name)) {
        //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\phpscripts\functions.php on line 39

        echo "Player $name already exists.<br />";
        //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\phpscripts\functions.php on line 57

    // Notice the curly braces around the else
    } else {

        queryMysql("INSERT INTO players    
        VALUES '$name', '$age', '$birthdate', '$element', '$allegiance'"); // and this ;

    }
}
```

I also noticed you have `};` at the end - that `;` is not required. You'll also likely run into problems with that query, so better to use single quotes when you're wrapping with double quotes.

Comment: changed those errors and code to reflect that. still getting
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\phpscripts\functions.php on line 61

Comment: The code I've posted shouldn't produce that error. I'd look through what you've got and make sure: Each function has an opening and closed set of `{ }`, that each statement line ends with a ; (Unless you have a new line INSIDE a set of quotes like your `queryMysql` function). Make sure your if statement has a set of `{ }` and if you have an else, it is preceeded by and followed by braces like `} else {`

Answer (score 2):

You try to execute variable $tableExists as a function. Try to use

```
if (tableExists($name)) {
    echo "Player $name already exists.<br />";
} else {
    queryMysql("INSERT INTO players VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$birthdate', '$element', '$allegiance')");
}
```

if you have such function.

Comment: yeah i changed that and added the other function for context still having errors though.